# WAR deployment to tomcat fails to start

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have a WAR packaged web Spring Boot application which works just fine when started with `java -jar ...`

When I try to deploy it on Tomcat I see an issue `Failed to instantiate WebApplicationInitializer class` and the reason is that my class does not have a default constructor. But my question is:- is it something which can be fixed? As I'm not quite sure how `java -jar ...` is capable of starting the application and use a @Autowired constructor with some parameters.

Obviously I'm not well versed in Spring, so please forgive me if the question is silly.

Thank you in advance!